# Nativescript Angular Detect Swipe to Back for IOS

Tags: ios, angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

In Nativescript Angular, I can swipe from left edge to right to go back on iOS. Is there any way i can detect or capture this swipe back?

The reason for this is because I have a button on screen that execute "**this.routerExtensions.back()**" when tapped. I would like to identify whether a "Back action" is from this button or iOS swipe event.
Thanks

Comment: Any info on this? I want to disable the gesture as well.

Comment: I suppose that it's fairly simple. Just identify your button click somehow. Whatever navigation was performed you can identify if it was a button

Comment: Is there anyway to detect the swipe back? or the navigation is by back or swipe back?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I was able to solve it for Android and iOS:

1. adjust constructor to manipulate the pullToLeft function from Android, and disable the default swipe back from iOS:

```js
constructor(...) {
    if (isAndroid) {
      Application.android.on(
        AndroidApplication.activityBackPressedEvent,
        (data: AndroidActivityBackPressedEventData) => {
          data.cancel = true;
          ...yourCustomFunction()
        }
      );
    } else {
      page.enableSwipeBackNavigation = false;
    }
  }
```

2. for Android it is already working - for iOS you need then to write a function you can use on a template (**this is also how you can recognize the swipe action**):

```js
public onSwipe = (args: SwipeGestureEventData) => {
    if (!isAndroid) {
      if (args.direction === SwipeDirection.right) {
        ...yourCustomFunction()
      }
    }
  };
```

3. disable the default PopGestureSerializer and add the swipe function on top of your template/element and it should work on iOS as well:

```html
<StackLayout [interactivePopGestureRecognizer]="false" (swipe)='onSwipe($event)'>
...
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

NativeScript has this property on pages.

[https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/*ui_page*.page.html#enableswipebacknavigation](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_page_.page.html#enableswipebacknavigation)

If you set that to false, you should then be able to create your own gesture for going back. Even on native iOS, I am not sure you can directly tap into the back gesture without instead replacing it with your own.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to detect the swipe back and not disable it

Comment: As I said, you will probably have to disable it and then add your own swipe back gesture with the functionality you want. I am not sure how in depth NativeScript goes here, but if you can call the controller.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.addTarget() method, you might be able to add your own action which also gets called when that swipe back occurs.